# Memory Hog while using any browser

Tags: 17.10, ram, browser, memory-leak

I am using 64 bit Ubuntu 17.10 running on Intel Quad Core i5 M560 @ 2.67GHz with 3.7GB Ram and 75 G Hard Drive. I am running GNOME 3.26.2.

I have noticed that the Mem usage drastically increases as I use any browser. I have gone from Chrome to firefox to Opera to Chromium to Midori finally to Epiphany, with only slight improvement in results. I have also noticed that If I walk away with the browser open for more than an hour, I invariable come back to nearly non responsive computer with the memory consumption at full 100%. I am forced to kill the computer and restrat it.

Also , I find that closing the browser every 30 or so minutes does seem to help with performance, however, it is an extremly inefficient way to operate.

I only use the browser to get at Google Apps (Docs, drive mail, etc.) and no other application for the computer.

Please help me troubleshoot the issue and fix.

Comment: 3.7 GB of RAM hints to me you are using a 32-bit OS. What is the terminal output when you type: `uname -a`

Comment: Linux anoushka-Latitude-E6410 4.13.0-37-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 7 14:13:23 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: This is what I get... Linux anoushka-Latitude-E6410 4.13.0-37-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 7 14:13:23 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: The browser should use a lot of the available RAM, unless you need to use it for something else. If it's using a lot and preventing other programs from running then that's a problem. It sounds like the issue is with the Google Apps, that they have memory leaks - is it with all apps or a particular one, can you try leaving one open at a time to narrow it down?

Comment: It appears to be predominantly Google Drive. between my 2 comments, I had to recycle the machine as it froze when I refreshed the tab that has Google Drive open.

Comment: Yup you are definitely 64-bit OS. Try this Q&A for tips: https://askubuntu.com/questions/817966/google-chrome-will-take-up-my-memory-to-the-point-where-it-causes-my-computer-to/817995#817995

Comment: The OOM Killer shouldn't let your system get that bad, might want to look into it's configuration. And FYI 32-bit should use a little less memory in general, not sure how that would effect Chrome/ium and google apps though, if at all.

Comment: Also look out for the memory use of the gnome-shell process. Gnome Shell currently has a known memory leak issue. However, it should not be consuming additional memory while you are away from your computer, only while you are switching applications etc. Use system monitor to check which processes are the one that increasingly claim the memory.