# Ubuntu 18.04 hanging with browsers

Tags: 18.04, browser

I am having this problem in Ubuntu 18.04, my laptop gets stuck whenever I open two browsers or lot of tabs (10+) and I have to wait for at least 10-15 mins before it becomes normal. I cleaned up my browser data and installed scripts such as *noscript* thinking that it might be some malware or miner script but even after this, the problem is still there.

Before 18.04, I was having Ubuntu 16.04 and it never got stuck even if I was using 2 browsers and multiple applications. 
Any fix for this ?

Comment: Xubuntu or Ubuntu? You've tagged this with `xubuntu`.

Comment: Ubuntu only, fixing this.

Comment: Have you monitored RAM when things get sticky?

Comment: Setup Chrome to **not** keep running after it's closed. Hopefully this reduces 10 minute wait for normalcy. Also see this answer to monitor misbehaving tab eating all your RAM: https://askubuntu.com/questions/817966/google-chrome-will-take-up-my-memory-to-the-point-where-it-causes-my-computer-to/817995#817995

Comment: DK Bose, unable to even monitor RAM at that time because everything is hung and I can't do anything except wait or press power button to restart Laptop. 

@WinEunuuchs2Unix: I will try this. Hope for the best.