# Memory over-consumption: gnome-shell? google-chrome? slack?

Tags: google-chrome, gnome-shell, 19.04, memory-usage, slack

I am having issues on a ubuntu 19.04 computer: regular freezes, ...

## Monitoring screenshots (htop)

### During a memory overload...

[image: Memory overload]

(Unfortunately I didn't think of hiding userland threads on the 1<sup>st</sup>, sorry for all the duplicate lines)

### After a fresh boot, with no app launched...

[image: fresh boot]

### After a fresh boot, with only google chrome launched...

[image: chrome only]

### After a fresh boot, with only slack launched...

[image]

## Details

From what I understand, it could be a memory problem with gnome-shell, google chrome, or slack, ...

On the "memory overload" screenshot, it seems like `gnome-shell` was consuming ~40% of memory. Is it normal behavior?

Here is the gnome-shell version

```
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.32.0
```

Here are the installed gnome-shell extensions:

```
elouan_keryell-even@baume:~$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 elouan_keryell-even elouan_keryell-even 4096 juin   5 15:15 .
drwx------ 3 elouan_keryell-even elouan_keryell-even 4096 juin   6 12:06 ..
drwxrwxr-x 4 elouan_keryell-even elouan_keryell-even 4096 juin   5 15:15 desktop-icons@csoriano
```

As for Google Chrome, here is its version: 73.0.3683.103-1

[image]

Comment: No, something is really wrong. Either with GNOME extensions, or with Chrome. You're swapping like crazy. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Also, reboot, and then show me `htop` BEFORE using Chrome. Are you using a beta of Chrome?

Comment: @heynnema I added chrome version to the question. I don't remember having installed a beta version, but maybe it is. Also, Imma add info on gnome-shell extensions.

Comment: @heynnema Imma add htop screenshot just after boot.

Comment: Related: [Google Chrome will take up my memory to the point where it causes my computer to freeze to a near halt. What can I do to prevent this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817966/google-chrome-will-take-up-my-memory-to-the-point-where-it-causes-my-computer-to/817995)

Comment: @heynnema ok I added a `htop` screenshot from just-after-boot.

Comment: Do you use slack? It's beta software, and it's not sandboxed. Now start Chrome and then using htop, monitor to see if a bunch of gnome-shell processes show up, or a bunch of chrome processes show up. Also try with slack. Chrome needs update/reinstall as it's an older, possibly field test or beta version. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I added the requested screenshots. Also, I upgraded chrome to the latest available version: 75.0.3770.80

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I installed chrome extension "The Great Suspender", as per this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/817971/412393

Comment: @ElouanKeryell-Even except for the first screenshot, everything looks normal. So you're going to have to run as normal, monitoring htop, until you see multiple instances of gnome-shell, and lots of swap being used. If Chrome is a beta/field test, remove it and install a standard version.

Comment: @heynnema ok. thanks a lot for spending time helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

### [ps_mem](https://github.com/pixelb/ps_mem)

I found `ps_mem` (a Python script) really useful to debug this kind of issues.

Download the ps_mem script, `chmod u+x` it, open to read it, and if you find it trustworthy just `sudo ./ps_mem.py`.

You can then use it several ways, like listing by user:

```
for i in $(ps -e -o user= | sort | uniq); do   printf '%-20s%10s\n' $i $(sudo ./ps_mem.py --total -p $(pgrep -d, -u $i)); done | sort -rn -k2 -t' '
```

Or a certain user, like root or your user (`$USER`):

```
sudo ./ps_mem.py -p $(pgrep -d, -u $USER)
```

In your case, I would move to [Brave](https://brave.com/linux/) (Chromium based, like [Ungoogled Chromium](https://ungoogled-software.github.io/)) or [Firefox](https://firefox.com/), remove any unnecessary extensions (both [on GNOME Shell](https://askubuntu.com/a/1266576/349837) and browser). Also check if you really need to have `mysqld` running all the time. Maybe consider using podman (better than docker) for temporary projects.